# How to view previous array value on click

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray

Here i used this code to view the next value in the array,

```
-(IBAction)changenext
{
static int j = 0;
if (j >arcount)
{
   j = 0;
}
 lb1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:[artext objectAtIndex:j]];
 imager.image=[arimage objectAtIndex:j];
 aplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:[arsound objectAtIndex:j] error:nil];

j++;
}
```

How to view the previous array value by other button click?Please help me to solve..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)change_next_or_prev:(id)sender
{
static int j = 0;
if(sender == btnNext)
    j++;
else if(sender == btnPrev)
    j--;
if (j >= arcount)
{
   j = 0;
}
else if(j < 0)
{
   j = arcount - 1;
}
 lb1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:[artext objectAtIndex:j]];
 imager.image=[arimage objectAtIndex:j];
 aplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:[arsound objectAtIndex:j] error:nil];
}
```

link both button to the same action.

Comment: good answer, you can also use the tag property of the buttons in IB and use those to distinguish between buttons if you don't really have to declare them as outlets.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)changeprev
{
static int j = arcount;
if (j < 0)
{
   j = arcount;
}
 lb1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:[artext objectAtIndex:j]];
 imager.image=[arimage objectAtIndex:j];
 aplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:[arsound objectAtIndex:j] error:nil];

j--;
}
```